# VBA access drop downs properly in a website

Tags: html, ms-access, vba

I'm having a bit of a problem. I'm hoping some VBA guru's can help me with. I have a website that has drop down options I'd like to be able to select. Right now my code is off and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I looked over the website trying to find out what I was doing wrong but nothing I found that could answer my question directly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub CMReportExport()
    Dim IEapp As Object
    Dim WebUrl As String
    Dim yearList As Object
    Dim prefixList As Object
    Dim versionList As Object

    Set IEapp = CreateObject("InternetExplorerMedium.Application")
    'Set IEapp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    WebUrl = "http://reporthub/Enterprise/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSupply+Chain%2fProduction%2fContribution+Margin%2fNonFood%2fNonFood+CM+RetailCat"

    With IEapp
        .Silent = True
        .Visible = True
        .navigate WebUrl
    End With
    While IEapp.Busy Or IEapp.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend '<== Ensure page loaded

    Set yearList = IEapp.document.querySelectorAll("#ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue option")  '<==apply CSS selector to get nodeList
    Set prefixList = IEapp.document.querySelectorAll("#ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_ddValue option")
    Set versionList = IEapp.document.querySelectorAll("#ctl32_ctl04_ctl07_ddValue option")

    yearList.item(2).Selected = True  'Index into nodeList e.g. second item is at index 2 = year 2018
    prefixList.item(2).Selected = True
    versionList.item(1).Selected = True

    'Set IEapp.getElementById("ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue").selectedvalue = 2 'Year
    'Set IEapp.getElementById("ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_ddValue").selectedvalue = DA 'Prefix
    'Set IEapp.getElementById("ctl32_ctl04_ctl07_ddValue").selectedvalue = 1 'Version
End Sub
```

The HTML elements (a chunk) are as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td class="ParamLabelCell"><label for="ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue"><span>Year</span></label>
    </td>
    <td class="ParamEntryCell" style="padding-right:0px;"><div id="ctl32_ctl04_ctl03">
        <select name="ctl32$ctl04$ctl03$ddValue" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl32$ctl04$ctl03$ddValue\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue" disabled="disabled">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">&lt;Select&nbsp;a&nbsp;Value&gt;</option>
            <option value="1">2019</option>
            <option value="2">2018</option>
            <option value="3">2017</option>
            <option value="4">2016</option>
            <option value="5">2015</option>
        </select>
        </div></td><td class="InterParamPadding"></td><td class="ParamLabelCell"><label for="ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_ddValue"><span disabled="disabled">Offer</span></label></td><td class="ParamEntryCell" style="padding-right:0px;"><div id="ctl32_ctl04_ctl05">
            <select name="ctl32$ctl04$ctl05$ddValue" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl32$ctl04$ctl05$ddValue\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_ddValue" disabled="disabled" class="EmptyDropDown">
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr IsParameterRow="true">
    <td class="ParamLabelCell"><label for="ctl32_ctl04_ctl07_ddValue"><span disabled="disabled">Version</span></label></td>
    <td class="ParamEntryCell" style="padding-right:0px;"><div id="ctl32_ctl04_ctl07">
    <select name="ctl32$ctl04$ctl07$ddValue" id="ctl32_ctl04_ctl07_ddValue" disabled="disabled" class="EmptyDropDown">
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat:**

I can't test against that webpage and there is not enough HTML to know if there are forms/frames and the like to also negotiate. The following is based on the HTML snippet provided. Mileage may vary.

---

**CSS selectors:**

You can use CSS selectors to target elements. For example you can get all the `year` options with the following selector, and then index into the returned nodeList:

```
#ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue option
```

The above selector says all elements with `option` tag that have parent element with id  `ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue`. `"#"` is the id selector.

There is not enough HTML to advise on the other elements you are targeting for sure but see my suggestions at the bottom. This illustrates the principle of using CSS selectors to target elements by page styling. More info on CSS selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

---

**CSS query results on HTML section provided:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**Getting the nodeList and selected an option - VBA:**

As more than one element is matched, `querySelectorAll` method is used to apply the selector and return the `nodeList` of matching elements.

For example:

```
While IEapp.Busy Or IEapp.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend '<== Ensure page loaded
Dim yearList As Object
Set yearList = IEapp.document.querySelectorAll("#ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue option")  '<==apply CSS selector to get nodeList
yearList.item(1).Selected = True  'Index into nodeList e.g. second item is at index 1 = year 2019
```

Assuming similar pattern for your other two option lists:

```
Dim prefixList As Object, versionList As Object
Set prefixList = IEapp.document.querySelectorAll("#ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_ddValue option") 
Set versionList = IEapp.document.querySelectorAll("#ctl32_ctl04_ctl07_ddValue option")
```

Then index into those.

If problems with   While IEapp.Busy Or IEapp.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend then try the following instead:

```
While IEapp.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
Dim waitUntil As Date
waitUntil = Now + TimeValue("00:00:11")  '<==Adjust additional wait time in seconds here
Do
  DoEvents
Loop Until Now >= waitUntil
```

---

**XMLHttpRequest (XHR)**

You are currently using IE browser which is a slow method for scraping. It may be possible for you to retrieve the required info by issuing an XHR POST request. I can't test against that page but you can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [here](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/).

Comment: I've used your suggestions but getting a debug error saying "Method 'Busy' of object 'IWebBrowser 2' Failed. It's focusing on the `While IEapp.Busy or IEapp.ReadyState < 4` of the code

Comment: Try with Set IEapp = CreateObject("InternetExplorerMedium.Application")

Comment: Also, when the error occurs execute the following in the immediate window (Ctrl + G) ...  type into Immediate window ? TypeName(IEapp)     and then press enter

Comment: Used your update. No luck. I also thought maybe I was missing a reference library but looks like I have them all. CTRL G got a window saying "Automation error the object invoked has disconnected from its clients". BTW Thanks for all your help on this!!!

Comment: Ctrl + G should bring up an empty window which is the immediate window. You type into that by placing cursor inside that window. And did you get the same error with the InternetExplorerMedium?

Comment: Also, have you been able to interact with the page at all before?

Comment: Nope haven't been able to interact with the page before. Yeah getting same error. However I made a quick change and now I'm getting a new runtime error "ActiveX component can't create object", Also if I use the Immediate with this error I get "Object Variable or With Block Variable not set".

Comment: Made the changes now getting a compile error. Says "Method or data member not found" Immediate shows expected: expression

Comment: It's on the While statement. It's highlighting  "Wait" in the command line.

Comment: I am not sure what the etiquette is on updating your question with my answer but others may see a problem they can solve with your original code. I don't mind but it may be simpler to keep your original question.

Comment: Would it be better to run this through Excel?

Comment: You could also try with Excel for sure. Looks like Application.Wait belongs to Excel but I have tried an alternative as well above.

Comment: used your updates, and tried it in Excel. It's coming back with an automation error that says "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients". This is coming in on that While command line again.

Comment: So the connection is dropping out.  You have intermittent signal? If you have added reference to Microsoft Internet Controls then you can try Dim ieAPP As New InternetExplorer.   Or additionally retry Dim ieAPP As New InternetExplorerMedium

Comment: Nope, but this is on our intranet. That might be the cause? I'll make sure Microsoft internet controls are there and give that a shot. Want to thank you again for all your help with this!!!!

Comment: It may absolutely be to do with Intranet. For starters you need to check whether the security settings are at medium.

Comment: Yep set to medium-high. I'll contact our admin's see what can be done.

Comment: Any luck with this? Perplexing to say the least.

Comment: Have a meeting this week about it with the admin of our reporting tools. Hopefully we can find a way to make it work. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: No unfortunately not. There seems to be some issue with permissions that can't be resolved.